# shopify liquid collection loop

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-app

## How Do I Write a Shopify collection loop that will:
- list only collections that contain more than 10 products
- list the collection title
- link the collection title to the collection url

Answer (score 1):

You should read the Shopify docs since this is very basic.

```
{% for collection in collections %}
    {% if collection.products_count > 10 %}
        <h4>
            <a href="{{ collection.url }}">{{ collection.title }}</a>
        </h4>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```